# Is the logarithm of sum of multiple variables with the constraint on sum of them Concave?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I know that without any constraint $log \sum_{i=1:1:m} \alpha_i C_i $  is not Concave but I am wondering is this function Concave when we have the constraint that $ \sum_{i=1:1:m} \alpha_i  =1 $ and they are positive? C is simple constant vector (with all non-zero elements).

Comment: In fact, the logarithm is perhaps the prototypical *concave* function. It is strictly concave over its entire domain, including therefore over any convex subset of it.

Comment: I agree there are issues with terminology here as pointed out by @MichaelGrant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bit of a terminology issue here. The status of a function as convex or concave is not affected by whether or not you "have constraints". You are talking about the context of convex optimization, though, so I think we can affirmatively answer the question I think you're *trying* to ask, and in the process correct the terminology.

As I said in the comments, your function $f(\alpha)=\log\sum_i C_i \alpha_i$ is concave. This means that the *optimization problem*
$$\text{maximize} ~ f(\alpha)$$
is convex. Again: the *function* is concave, the *optimization problem* is convex. That's because convex optimization problems can either involve 1) minimizing a convex function or 2) maximizing a concave function. I do *not* get to say that my concave function $f$ is convex just because I'm using it in a valid convex optimization model. (If the machine learning community is doing this, they need to stop. Lead the charge!)

Now, of course, an *optimization model* can "have" constraints, as you say. In your case, you seem to want this:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}   & \log \sum_{i=1}^m C_i \alpha_i \\
\text{subject to} &  \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i = 1 \\ & \alpha_i \geq 0, ~ i=1,2,\dots, m
\end{array}
This remains a convex optimization problem, because 1) I'm maximizing a concave objective and 2) all of my constraints are individually convex. But again, the *function* $f$ is still concave.

If you're really determined to stick to *functions*, then what you might say is that the *domain* of the function $f$ is artificially constrained. For instance:
$$f(\alpha) \triangleq \sum_i \log_{i=1}^m C_i\alpha_i, \quad \mathop{\textrm{dom}} f \triangleq
\left\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^m\,|\,\alpha\succeq 0, \vec{1}^T\alpha=1\right\}$$
In this case we've *defined* the domain of the function to be limited to the simplex using the constraints. A necessary condition for a function to be concave is that its domain is a convex set, which is satisfied here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no (if I understand the question correctly). The function 
$$\log(x +1), $$ 
which is not convex, is of the form you gave with 
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
x=\alpha_1 & 1-x=\alpha_2, & C_1=2 , & C_2=1. 
\end{array}
$$

Comment: thanks Giuseppe, But I didn't catch your idea exactly. we know that x>=0 and x<=1. so you say that log(x+1) is not convex for 0<=x<=1?

Comment: Oh, I edit my question 25 minute ago and you answered it 22 minute ago. so you may didn't see the edit to the question:"constraint that ∑i=1:1:mαi=1∑i=1:1:mαi=1 and they are positive". I am really sorry

Comment: Well, doesn't really matter as indeed $\log(1+x)$ is not convex on the interval $x\in [0, 1]$.

Comment: It is still non-convex even with the constraint.

Comment: the second derivative of log(1+x) is -1/((1+x)^2) which is always <0 for x>=0 and x<=1 and so it is concave. I think I missed the point on how this is not a concave function.

Comment: I think we missed the fact you were asking about convex *or* concave.

Comment: @MichaelGrant yes. I edit the question title to make the question more formally. In fact in machine learning field saying Convex implies the meaning of being "Convex or Concave" BTW I am sorry if the title was not clear.

Comment: If that is genuinely the case, then the field of machine learning needs to correct itself. My suspicion however is that there is context here that is missing. For example, a *convex optimization problem* can involve the maximization of a concave function---but that doesn't allow me to claim the objective function is "convex".